# Tkinter not replacing Tk.Label after calling destroy() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I extended Tk.Label class in order to customize my needs, and for some odd reason is not destroying the object, even after calling the `widget.destroy()`, when I am updating values. So basically, I would end up with the `self.update` old value on bottom and new value on top of old value.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.master = master

    self.update = Label(self.master, "Select a value", 0, 0)

    btn = tk.Button(text="Select", command=self.update_btn)
    btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

  def update_btn(self):
    # Destroy method being called here
    self.update.destroy()
    self.update = Label(self.master, "New value", 0, 0)

class Label(tk.Label):
  def __init__(self, root, label_name, row, col, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    label = tk.Label(root, text=label_name, *args, **kwargs)
    label.grid(row=row, column=col)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: to update text in `Label` (or `Button`) you can do `self.update["text"] = "New value"`

Comment: your class is weird - it creates `Label` in `Label` so you have  to use `self.label` and then remove `self.update.label.destroy()`

Comment: Yeah, I probably need to rename the class names in order not to confuse `Tk.Label` and `Label` class, `self.update.label["text"]` from you solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is weird. You create `Label` inside `Label` and you shows only inner label. And later you destroy outer label but it will not destroy inner label.

Correct version is

```
class Label(tk.Label):

    def __init__(self, root, label_name, row, col, *args, **kwargs):
       tk.Label.__init__(self, *args, master=root, text=label_name, **kwargs)
       self.grid(row=row, column=col)
```

In Python 3.x you can write it

```
class Label(tk.Label):

    def __init__(self, root, label_name, row, col, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, master=root, text=label_name, **kwargs)
        self.grid(row=row, column=col)
```

Now to update text you can use

```
self.update["text"] = "..."
```

or

```
self.update.config(text="...")
```

instead of `self.update.label["text"] = ...

---

**EDIT:** class `GUI` is also weird. You creat `Frame` but you don't show it (you don't use pack/grid) and you use main window as parent for `Label`. For `Button` you don't even set parent so you may get weird result in some situations.

```
import tkinter as tk


class GUI(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, master=master, **kwargs)

      # show frame
      self.pack()

      # add to frame (self)
      self.update = Label(self, "Select a value", 0, 0)

      # add to frame (self)
      btn = tk.Button(self, text="Select", command=self.update_btn)
      btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

  def update_btn(self):
      self.update['text'] = "New value"
      #self.update.config(text="New value")


class Label(tk.Label):

    def __init__(self, root, label_name, row, col, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, master=root, text=label_name, **kwargs)
       self.grid(row=row, column=col)


root = tk.Tk()
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```